# Integrating external data source with Cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, feature-file

I am new to Cucumber and the feature files it uses for BDD. I want to know if there is any way I could directly give the filepath of my external data file (eg. CSV file), and fetch the values of the parameters I use to create my test script.

Comment: See this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158660/using-csv-file-in-cucumber-watir-ruby/21158858#21158858

Comment: link is broken dude.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tag with parameter to the features

```
@data("/path/data.json")
  Scenario: Login as zinc admin
    Given I open zinc homepage
```

And then create hook that reads the param and loads file before running a scenario.

```
Before do |scenario|
  // read data from tag param
end
```

Comment: Could share  Java code snippet better way to understand this

Comment: can you please provide JSON structure or any article/link/post regarding same. if it require any more snippet kindly share that too

Comment: do you have a project on github ? I can help you by creating this logic. You will have to add a before hook, read tag value, and load data from the path

Comment: see in before hook we can read data from excel that I already done. the problem is as the example data is out of feature it become scenario not scenario outline which run the scenario only one time. If i put loop in step definition function then if any one data example fails it failed the entire scenario which make it unreliable